# How do I autohide the top panel in Unity?

Tags: unity, panel, autohide

When windows are not maximized, the top panel is basically wasted space for me in Unity.

Is there a way to make it autohide? i.e. make it appear on mouse over.

Comment: I could not find a launchpad bug, so I've created one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1517733 Let's upvote it until it gets done.

Answer (score 20):

You can't currently autohide the panel in Unity. It is also not a planned feature.

There are ways you could possibly make the panel autohide:

- Post an idea on [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) to add this option and hope a developer sees it and implements it or creates a for with this feature.
- Report a bug on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+filebug) stating that this option should be available and hope a developer sees it and implements it or creates a for with this feature. This will probably get marked as opinion or invalid or at best a wishlist bug.
- Get the [code](https://code.launchpad.net/unity) and add this option then merge with trunk or create your own fork.

None of these are immediate or even likely.

Comment: With the global menu gone, this is a giant waste of space, in particular on modern 21:9 screens.

Comment: Glaringly obvious waste of space.

Comment: I've created a launchpad bug: http://askubuntu.com/a/699885/52975

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 Santilli Bug is here :) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1517733

Comment: @StephenNiedzielski thanks! Work should lead to rep. Sigh ~~

Answer (score 1):

You can make it transparent. With ComprizConfig Settings Manager installed and the Unity plugin enabled you can change the panel's opacity to zero under the Experimental tab. With a light background and light coloured text or a dark background and dark coloured the panel will almost disappear but the icons and menu links will still be there.

Comment: and it will still waste space - this doesn't really change anything. Unless the op's question was of a purely aesthetical nature

Comment: And what is more will not help at all while gaming. Windowed full screen games are snapped to top task bar, so your game in full screen more will end up behind edges of the screen. Well done Unity. :D