# How can I get the Nautilus icon to display on the panel?

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, display, panel

This seems to be so obvious and simple but I can't see any quick way to achieve it in Lucid. Because Nautilus does not appear in a menu there seems to be no obvious way of right-clicking and showing it on the panel.

Comment: The answer to this question might be helpful. http://askubuntu.com/questions/115672/why-cant-the-unity-panel-be-hidden

Comment: @StephenMyall I think I did not describe the question properly. I want Nautilus to show on the panel.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood.  Open gnome-tweak-tool (Advanced Settings) and turn on the switch that says 'Have file manager handle the desktop'.  If this doesnt work I will leave this for someone else to answer:  sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool if you havent got it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's hope I understood the question correctly. You're on Lucid and want a Nautilus launcher on the top panel ? Then go to Menu->Places->Nautilus, click and slide to the panel. You can also create the launcher (right-click on panel I believe) and set the command to "nautilus" or "nautilus /path/to/my/folder"

Comment: dragging the from the menu worked in Hardy. On Lucid dragging wouldn't work. I used the second method to do it. I expected to find Nautilus in the list of icons when I first tried. Typing brought it up