# VirtualBox 4.3.16 issue with Unity Launcher

Tags: virtualbox

I just updated to VirtualBox 4.3.16 and now when putting my guest OS in fullscreen the Unity launcher stays over the top of the screen. This makes using full screen unworkable.

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion to fix this issue?

Comment: Your screenshot shows expected behaviour when we **maximize** then VBox window. But admittedly it is also an issue on fullscreen (HOST + F)... may likely be [bug #734908](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/734908) - switching to auto-hide the Launcher solves the Launcher issue but the top panel will still be in the way :(

Comment: Also related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115672/why-cant-the-unity-panel-be-hidden

Comment: Oops... yep, I took the screen shot with the window Maximized. Good catch.

Comment: One suggested fix was to use the [4.3.17 guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.17-96003.iso), but that didn't work for me.

Comment: This issue was fixed for a long time, and also with VirtualBox 5. With `virtualbox-5.0/unknown,now 5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty` this exact issue returned.  Adding this comment so other user can see. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling mini-toolbar in VMs settings is a temporary work-around. In the VirtualBox manager go to Settings->General->Advanced tab -> Mini ToolBar [] Show in Fullscreen/Seamless and make sure it is *unchecked*

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is a known issue with VirtualBox as reported on the [VirtualBox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=63554). Presently there is no fix. Most users are rolling back to 4.3.14.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem over here running Virtualbox 4.3.16 host on Windows7 and as client Ubuntu 14.04.1 (kernel 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:45 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux).

Found a reasonable workaround. Hit CONTROL-ALT-DELETE and make your choice to CANCEL. Guess itś related to X-server. Had it in the past with 12.04 or 12.10. Seems behavior is back again :-). Someone already raised a bugreport???

What also works is to minimize Ubuntu client when it's starting (booting). Maybe something with X-Server (X11) or the support for it on VirtualBox.