# How can I maximise apps in a mac-like way?

Tags: unity, window-manager

I had to use Mac for a while (glad I'm back to g'old Ubuntu). It did have one feature I got used to: when I maximised a window it hid all the panels and only showed my app. I know this is essentially a full-screen.

What I am interested in is finding a way to hide all panes in ubuntu when using a keyboard shortcut to maximise a window. I could also be tied to a specific workspace if that is easier. Ideally I would like to have multiple terminal windows open in that full screen mode. I use keyboard shortcuts to place terminal windows where I want them all the time and I'd want to keep that.

I am looking into ideas to

1. hide launcher ([Shortcut to change Launcher 'Hide' setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41241/shortcut-to-change-launcher-hide-setting))
2. hide panels

and combine them in a keyboard shortcut

Comment: To get that effect, install this `sudo apt install wmctrl`  then you can `fullscreen` the active window with `F11` or `wmctrl -r ":ACTIVE:" -b toggle,fullscreen` is this what you wanted?

Comment: Can it fullscreen multiple terminal windows?

Comment: How do you mean? You can have as many windows as you like fullscreen at the same time and use the launcher or task switcher to change between them.

Comment: Well I don't really want fullscreen, I want to get rid of the launcher and panels and still have the possibility to put my terminal windows where I want (in a panel-free view).

Comment: OK then this is not what you want then. You can hide the launcher bar from system settings and appearance but AFAIK you cant hide the top panel (or make it dodge windows). Some references: http://askubuntu.com/questions/557107/is-there-a-way-to-configure-unitys-top-bar-to-autohide http://askubuntu.com/questions/53662/how-do-i-autohide-the-top-panel-in-unity https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2201585 I think because of the global menu, Unity simply does not do this. Something like Mate or XFCE or KDE could likly do this.